# Make template function to destinguish inheritors and others

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

I have a class (`base`) which has many inheritors (`derived_i`) and some other types (`other`). I want to have a template method in some class-handler (`caller`), which handles inheritors of `base` in differ way, then from other types.

Here is an example code I telling about.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class base {
public:
    base (T val = T())
        : m_val(val)
    {}
    base (const base &other)
        : base(other.m_val)
    {}
    virtual void base_specific_method()
    {
        cout << __func__ << " method called: " << m_val << endl;
    }
    void each_class_has_this() {
        cout << __func__ << " this is boring..." << endl;
    }
    T m_val;
};
class other {
public:
    void each_class_has_this() {
        cout << __func__ <<" this is boring..." << endl;
    }
};
class derived_i : public base <int>
{
public:
    derived_i () : base <int> (10)
    {}
    virtual void base_specific_method()
    {
        cout << __func__ <<" Hey! I'm interesting derived! And 10 == " << m_val << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class caller {
public:
    caller (T val = T())
        : m_val(val)
    {}
    void call() {
        p_call(m_val);
    }
private:
    template <typename T1> void p_call (T1 &val)
    {
        val.each_class_has_this();
    }
    template <typename T1> void p_call (base<T1> &val)
    {
        val.base_specific_method();
    }
private:
    T m_val;
};

int main ()
{
    caller<other> c1;
    caller<base<double> > c2;
    caller<derived_i > c3;

    c1.call();
    c2.call();
    c3.call();
}
```

It compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` and output is next:

```
  each_class_has_this this is boring...
  base_specific_method method called: 0
  each_class_has_this this is boring...
```

While I'm expecting

```
  each_class_has_this this is boring...
  base_specific_method method called: 0
  base_specific_method Hey! I'm interesting derived! And 10 == 10
```

Is there any way to change this code to make it suitable my requests?

This question seems to be a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988024/passing-a-derived-class-to-a-template-function-specialized-with-base-class), but the correct answer on it leads to the problem, I faced here.

P.S. There is no way to make `base` and `other` the inheritors from one class. =(

Comment: It won't solve your issue but here's a typo: `base_specific_method()` vs `base_speciffic_method()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a derived class to a template function specialized with base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988024/passing-a-derived-class-to-a-template-function-specialized-with-base-class)

Comment: @songyuanyao yep it is, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to distinguish the class derived from `base<T>` or not.

```
template <typename T, typename TT = void>
class caller {
public:
    caller (T val = T())
        : m_val(val)
    {}
    void call() {
        p_call(m_val);
    }
private:
    template <typename T1> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<base<TT>, T1>::value>::type p_call (T1 &val)
    {
        val.each_class_has_this();
    }
    template <typename T1> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<base<TT>, T1>::value>::type p_call(T1& val)
    {
        val.base_specific_method();
    }

private:
    T m_val;
};
```

Note that `base` is a template class, which means `T1` might be derived class of `base<int>`, or `base<double>`, and so on. We can't count all the possibilities, so the template parameter `TT` need to be specified as the hint. Then use it as:

```
caller<other> c1;
caller<base<double>, double> c2;
caller<derived_i, int> c3;  // derived_i derived from base<int>

c1.call();
c2.call();
c3.call();
```

Result:

```
each_class_has_this this is boring...
base_specific_method method called: 0
base_specific_method Hey! I'm interesting derived! And 10 == 10
```

<kbd>[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JDJBY28211)</kbd>

Or you can make a most base class to make it simple:

```
class abstract_base {
public:
    virtual void base_specific_method() = 0;
    virtual ~abstract_base() {}
};
template <typename T>
class base : public abstract_base {
    ...
};
...
template <typename T>
class caller {
    ...
    template <typename T1> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<abstract_base, T1>::value>::type p_call (T1 &val)
    {
        val.each_class_has_this();
    }
    template <typename T1> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<abstract_base, T1>::value>::type p_call(T1& val)
    {
        val.base_specific_method();
    }
    ...
};
```

<kbd>[LIVE2](http://rextester.com/EJDTR43245)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired behaviour using SFINAE:

Add a class `has_specific` like this:

```
template <typename T>
class has_specific
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template <typename C> static one test( typeof(&C::base_specific_method) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);    

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

And change your definition of `p_call` to this:

```
template <typename T1=T>
typename enable_if<!has_specific<T1>::value,void>::type
p_call (T1 &val)
{
    val.each_class_has_this();
}

template <typename T1=T>
typename enable_if<has_specific<T1>::value,void>::type
p_call (T1 &val)
{
    val.base_specific_method();
}
```

In this case i used the SFINAE in the return type. It should be possible to use it in the template arguments list or in the parameters list as well, but this one was the one i got working first.
As a technical detail, this implementation does not depend on if you have a class derived from `base`, but if a method `base_specific_method()` is present, but i hope it still helps with your problem.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/bOYugL)
[has_specific taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)
[return type SFINAE taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function)

Comment: New day - new news - new technologies! Thank you for the new part of C++ world.